# Run Flask in multi-threaded mode with crossbar.io

Tags: python, flask, crossbar

Is there a way to launch a Flask application in multi-threaded mode with the crossbar.io server?

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://crossbar.io/docs/WSGI-Host-Service/):

> The WSGI Web application runs on a pool of worker threads

You don't have to do anything.